# Python to csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am working on getting data into a csv file. The following script generates a list of data.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def trade_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'https://demosite.com' + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
        # just get the code, no headers or anything
        plain_text = source_code.text.encode('ascii', 'replace')
        # BeautifulSoup objects can be sorted through easy
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text,'html.parser')

        for price in soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'price'}):
            href = price.get('href')
            title = price.string  # just the text, not the HTML
            print(title)
            #get_single_item_data(href)

        page += 1

trade_spider(1)
```

When I run this script I get a list as such:

```
USD $25.00 /Each
USD $35.10 /Each
USD $414.00 /Box
USD $69.00 /Each
USD $234.00 /Box
```

I am relatively new and would like to understand how to export this data into a column of a csv file.

Comment: CSV is the initialism of Comma-Separated Values. Just add commas between each field, and for safety enclose the fields in double quotes (so that commas they may contain wouldn't be considered as field separator, or linefeeds as row separator). At this point your scripts outputs CSV data which you can redirect to a file or another script.

Comment: ```f = open('csvfile.csv','w')
f.write('hi there\n') 
f.close()```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, instead of printing it to stdout, you can send that string to a file, and name the file a csv.

```
f = open('scrapedoutput.csv','w+')
for price in soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'price'}):
        href = price.get('href')
        title = price.string  # just the text, not the HTML
        print(title)
        columns = title.split(" ")
        f.write(",".join(columns))
f.close()
```

Here split is first used to get the columns, and then join is used with "," to join the elements of the array with "," and write that to the file.

Comment: Thank you scarvish for your help! Unfortunately this generates the csv as follows: USD,$25.00,/EachUSD,$35.10,/EachUSD,$414.00,/BoxUSD,$69.00... I am looking to get each of the items into a row in one column. Alternatively, a pure numeric value would also work.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you want 
USD,$25.00,/Each on one line and USD,$35.10,/Each on another lines and so on right?
If so, then you just need to add a f.write("\n") after the first f.write line. Which essentially means you're adding a new line character after each row.